# Running Kickstart from Debian-based system: /dev/shm bind mount fails

Tags: mount, kickstart

The following failure occurs since `/dev/shm` is a symlink to `/run/shm` on newer Debian and Ubuntu systems. Is there a way to adjust this behavior in Kickstart so it tries to also mount from `/run/shm`? I would find this preferable to changing my default symlink to a bind mount. Ideally, this would be something I could define in the `.ks` file.

```
chroot builddir/media/centos6/x86_64/tools livecd-creator --config /build/livecd.ks

## Snip -- output from mke2fs and tune2fs

mount: special device /dev/shm does not exist
Error creating Live CD : Bind-mounting '/dev/shm' to '/var/tmp/imgcreate-ubTScl/install_root//dev/shm' failed
make: *** [builddir/media/centos6/x86_64/image.iso] Error 1
user@host:/tmp/workspace$ ls -lh /dev/shm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Aug 24 14:21 /dev/shm -> /run/shm
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello I was attempting the same within a chroot

```
[] $ sudo livecd-creator -c fedora-live-base.ks -f rhel6.2
Error creating Live CD : Bind-mounting '/dev/shm' to '/var/tmp/imgcreate-O5IVB2/install_root//dev/shm' failed
```

I came across

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_Existing_Linux

When chrooting Debian based host systems the `/dev/shm` points to `/run/shm`. `/run/shm` does not exist in the chroot environment and hence the link is broken and `pacstrap` returns an error.

Create a directory `/run/shm` in the chroot environment when chrooting from Debian based host systems

Once I created `/run/shm` in my chroot I was able to create the liveCD.